# Как работать с Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Решил тут попробовать написать онлайн-чат с использованием web-сокетов и как раз наткнулся на интересное видео (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROwCDBIP6fU), где вроде как подробно все рассказывают, решил по примеру создать такой же чат, но сразу же столкнулся с проблемой, т.к. в этом особо не разбираюсь (но очень хочется), то я не понял, как, точнее в какой среде разработки можно писать этот код? В примере указан Visual Studio Code. Установил, но написанный код не смог запустить. т.к. выдает ошибку, я даже подключиться элементарно не могу(( Делаю все, как в примере, но вот что выдает

> Отладка с помощью протокола прежней версии, так как была обнаружена
> версия Node v6.10.3.
>
> ```
> node --debug-brk=46243 --nolazy main.js 
> Debugger listening on [::]:46243
> ```

Не нашел в интернете  ответ на этот вопрос. Может я вообще что-то не то делаю?

> ```
> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
> at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
> at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97
> at Module._compile (module.js:542:28
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (mo
> at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:
> at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
> at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
> at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)`
> ```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если судить по приведённому сообщению, то у Вас всё запустилось.

Comment: @Yaant да, чет я погнал. Он мне на код ругается, но не могу понять, что не так? Уже пять раз пересмотрел, но не понимаю, что не так?

Comment: На скриншоте в рамочке у Вас вместо `function` написано `fucntion`.

Comment: исправил и даже что-то запустил (показывает сообщение `listening on *:3000`, как в примере), но сообщение он мне все равно не выводит в браузере, в чем может проблема? ошибок никаких не выдает.

Comment: все, настроил.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы: 
Надо было выполнить установку `npm install node-static && npm install ws`

Answer (score 2):

Как выше было сказано, у Вас не установлены необходимые модули. В частности, в скриншоте сообщается, что нет модуля express. А здесь "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument li" судя по всему пропущена кавычка.

Если у Вас Windows, то Node.JS ставится относительно просто - скачиваете с официального сайта дистрибутив, устанавливается его и менеджер пакетов (NPM), далее при работе с самим кодом скачиваете через менеджер необходимые модули (они загружаются в папку node_modules там же, где находится ваш проект).

Среда разработки любая, хоть блокнот (все, что позволяет редактировать текстовые файлы), но сам предпочитаю DreamViewer.

Если планируете писать чат, то для начала советую попробовать поработать с WS (socket.io более сложен в работе, т.к. он поддерживает не один, а целую группу протоколов, к тому же имеет отдельную клиентскую часть).